# Value not saving outside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, php-7

I update my code from PHP 5 to PHP 7 and i got problem with foreach loop. I loocked wor answers here, but none is working. Or i dont understand where i have problem

```
function getStructure($pid = 0, $expand = array(), $alevel = 0)
{
    $struct = array();
    if ( $alevel > $this->levelCount) $this->levelCount = (int)$alevel;

    $str = $this->dbStructure->getStructure($pid);
    foreach ($str as &$row)
    {
        if ($row["type"] == STRUCT_PAGE)
        {
            $row["editLink"]    = "editPage";
            $row["target"]        = "_self";
        }
        elseif ($row["type"] == STRUCT_MODULE)
        {
            $row["editLink"]    = "editModule";
            $row["target"]        = "_self";
        }
        elseif ($row["type"] == STRUCT_LINK)
        {
            $row["editLink"]    = "editLink";
            $row["target"]        = "_blank";
        }
        elseif ($row["type"] == STRUCT_CATALOG)
        {
            $row["editLink"]    = "editCatalog";
            $row["target"]        = "_self";
        }

        $row["childrens"] = $this->getStructure((int)$row["id"], $expand, $alevel+1);

        if ($row["type"] == STRUCT_CATALOG and isset($row["childrens"][0]["shortcut"]))
        {
            $row["shortcut"] = $row["childrens"][0]["shortcut"];
            $row["target"] = $row["childrens"][0]["type"] == STRUCT_LINK ? "_blank" : "_self";
        }

        $struct[] = $row;   
    }
    unset($row);
    return $struct;
}
```

All the time $struct is NULL and I need to be multidimensional array

Comment: Remove the ampersand in foreach.

Comment: Removing ampersand not helping. And when I var_dump inside the loop, some valuesar duplicated.

Comment: Same problem appers if i use for loop. I don't understand, where dissapers my &struct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code by itself is good. Has no problems, only ampersand is not needet. The problem was in different place. Sorry for spam